# Firebase get full path of reference URL in dataSnapshot (javascript API)

Tags: javascript, firebase

Say I have the following:

```
var firebaseARef = new Firebase("http://this.is.my/firebase/url/A/reference")
var firebaseBRef = new Firebase("http://this.is.my/firebase/url/B/reference")
```

When I define my `.on()` functions, I'd like to specify a single handler, and then do all of the handling in one place in my code, rather than having to define the functions inline with the `.on()` definition. To illustrate:

```
var handleAllFirebaseStuff = function(dataSnapshot){
    var name = dataSnapshot.name(); //PROBLEM HERE: returns "reference", no way to distinguish!
    switch(name){
       case "http://this.is.my/firebase/url/A/reference": //How do I get this full reference from dataSnapshot?
          /* do stuff for A reference */
       case "http://this.is.my/firebase/url/B/reference": //How do I get this full reference from dataSnapshot?
          /* do stuff for B reference */
       default:
          break;
    }
}

firebaseARef.on('value', handleAllFirebaseStuff);
firebaseBRef.on('value', handleAllFirebaseStuff);
```

The problem is `dataSnapshot.name()` will only return `"reference"` in both cases, making it impossible to distinguish between the two references in the switch/case statement!

I'm certain that `dataSnapshot` contains this information *somewhere*, but I have yet to uncover it in any convenient fashion. Exploring the `dataSnapshot`object in the console, I find that there is an object buried within called `path` that contains (among other things) an array, using the example above, that would contain `["firebase", "url", "A", "reference"]`, but there is no easy way to access it.

If I had access to that array, I could rebuild the URL or find a more convenient way to handle the switch/case statement. I think a full string of the reference would be more appropriate as an easily accessible value from `dataSnapshot`.

Comment: Are you looking for `snapshot.ref().toString()`?

Comment: That's the one! This being documented on Firebase's Javascript API would be tremendously helpful! If you'd like to provide the answer, I'll gladly accept it...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get back from a `Snapshot` to the full URL, you do:

```
snapshot.ref().toString()
```

The `toString` part is somewhat counter-intuitive. I often find myself having to test it, to see if that's indeed the way to go.

*hint* It would be nice if there was also a more explicit `getUrl` method *hint*

## UPDATE:

With recent SDK versions [`ref` is no longer a function](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#no-argument_getters_are_now_read-only_properties_numbered), so you'll have to use:

```
snapshot.ref.toString();
```

Comment: Yes! The API documentation for `DataSnapshot.ref()` in it's entirety is, "The Firebase reference for the location that generated this DataSnapshot." There is obviously more buried in here (i.e. .ref().toString()) -- let's see some more documentation! (or more helpful explicit methods _hint hint_)

Comment: Also, I'm glad that toString() works, but it being an undocumented method slightly scares me -- what if the method is totally changed in functionality between Firebase revs? (There is no guarantee it wont!) So, I agree with your statement about explicit method wholeheartedly - Firebase oughta move on this.

Comment: The fact that `ref.toString()` returns the full URL is documented: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/tostring.html "Gets the absolute URL corresponding to this Firebase reference's location."

Comment: If you want the relative path use: `snapshot.ref.path.toString();`